# Using doctests from within unittests

Tags: python

I typically write both unittests and doctests in my modules. I'd like to automatically run all of my doctests when running the test suite. I think this is possible, but I'm having a hard time with the syntax.

I have the test suite

```
import unittest
class ts(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_null(self): self.assertTrue(True)
if __name__ == '__main__': unittest.main()
```

I'd like to add to this suite all of the doctests in module `module1`. How can I do this? I've read the [python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/doctest.html#unittest-api), but I'm not any closer to success, here. Adding the lines

```
import doctest
import module1
suite = doctest.DocTestSuite(module1)
```

doesn't work. `unittest.main()` searches through the current file scope and runs every test **case** it finds, right? But DocTestSuite produces a test **suite**. How do I get `unittest.main()` to run the additional cases in the suite? Or am I just confused and deluded??

Once again, I'd be grateful for any help anyone can offer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this code i combined unittests and doctests from imported module

```
import unittest


class ts(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_null(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)


class ts1(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_null(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)

testSuite = unittest.TestSuite()    
testSuite.addTests(unittest.makeSuite(ts))
testSuite.addTest(unittest.makeSuite(ts1))

import doctest
import my_module_with_doctests

testSuite.addTest(doctest.DocTestSuite(my_module_with_doctests))
unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity = 2).run(testSuite)
```

Comment: Changed line breaks to make it a little more PEP8 friendly - just looked a bit weird to me and I couldn't help myself :(

Comment: At least in 2021 with Python 3.10 and `unittest discover` this leads to doubled execution of `ts` and `ts1`...

Answer (score 20):

An update to this old question: since Python version 2.7 there is the [load_tests protocol](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#load-tests-protocol) and there is no longer a need to write custom code. It allows you to add a function `load_tests()`, which a test loader will execute to update its collection of unit tests for the current module.

Put a function like this in your code module to package the module's own doctests into a test suite for `unittest`:

```
def load_tests(loader, tests, ignore):
    tests.addTests(doctest.DocTestSuite())
    return tests
```

Or, put a function like this into your unit test module to add the doctests from another module (for example, `package.code_module`) into the tests suite which is already there:

```
def load_tests(loader, tests, ignore):
    tests.addTests(doctest.DocTestSuite(package.code_module))
    return tests
```

When `unittest.TestLoader` methods `loadTestsFromModule()`, `loadTestsFromName()` or `discover()` are used unittest uses a test suite including both unit tests and doctests.

Comment: I just spent an hour trying to achieve what these three lines do!

Comment: It gets tricky when it comes to py.test. It doesn't support load_tests protocol for now.

Comment: Works like a charm! Also note it can be combined with regular unittest tests in the very same file.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend to use `pytest --doctest-modules` without any load_test protocol. You can simply add both the files or directories with your normal pytests and your modules with doctests to that pytest call.

> pytest --doctest-modules path/to/pytest/unittests path/to/modules

It discovers and runs all doctests as well.

See https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/doctest.html

Answer (score 1):

This code will automatically run the doctests for all the modules in a package without needing to manually add a test suite for each module.  This can be used with Tox.

```
import doctest
import glob
import os
import sys
if sys.version_info < (2,7,):
    import unittest2 as unittest
else:
    import unittest

import mypackage as source_package

def load_module_by_path(path):
    """Load a python module from its path.

    Parameters
    ----------
    path : str
        Path to the module source file.

    Returns
    -------
    mod : module
        Loaded module.
    """
    import imp

    module_file_basename = os.path.basename(path)
    module_name, ext = os.path.splitext(module_file_basename)
    mod = imp.load_source(module_name, path)
    return mod

def file_contains_doctests(path):
    """Scan a python source file to determine if it contains any doctest examples.

    Parameters
    ----------
    path : str
        Path to the module source file.

    Returns
    -------
    flag : bool
        True if the module source code contains doctest examples.
    """
    with open(path) as f:
        for line in f:
            if ">>>" in line:
                return True
    return False

def load_tests(loader, tests, pattern):
    """Run doctests for all modules"""
    source_dir = os.path.dirname(source_package.__path__[0])
    python_source_glob = os.path.join(source_dir, source_package.__name__, "*.py")
    python_source_files = glob.glob(python_source_glob)
    for python_source_file in python_source_files:
        if not file_contains_doctests(python_source_file):
            continue
        module = load_module_by_path(python_source_file)
        tests.addTests(doctest.DocTestSuite(module))
    return tests
```

Answer (score 0):

First I tried accepted answer from Andrey, but at least when running in Python 3.10 and `python -m unittest discover` it has led to running the test from unittest twice. Then I tried to simplify it and use `load_tests` and to my surprise it worked very well:

So just write both `load_tests` and normal `unittest` tests in a single file and it works!

```py
import doctest
import unittest

import my_module_with_doctests


class ts(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_null(self):
        self.assertTrue(False)


# No need in any other extra code here


# Load doctests as unittest, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html#unittest-api
def load_tests(loader, tests, ignore):
    tests.addTests(doctest.DocTestSuite(my_module_with_doctests))
    return tests
```